# Как построить график функции?

Tags: c#

Нужно построить график [овалов кассини](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Овал_Кассини) в полярных координатах и зафиксировать в 3-х состояниях. В VS2010 не могу найти ни одного рабочего кода даже. Может хоть литература у кого-нибудь есть какая.

Answer (score 1):

Есть очень много библиотек, которые позволяют рисовать графики достаточно просто. Очень хорошая - [Dynamic Data Display](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/groups/science/tools/d3/dynamicdatadisplay.htm). [Страница на CodePlex](http://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com/). Сначала формируете два массива (или IEnumerable) для пар точек x, y. А затем рисуете:

```
linegraph.Plot(x,y);
```

Прописываете в XAML строки:

```
<d3:Chart BottomTitle="Argument" LeftTitle="Function">
    <d3:LineGraph x:Name="linegraph" />
</d3:Chart>
```

И получаете линейный график.

P.S. Ну и всегда можно строить по точкам на [Graphics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Чартом в C# пользоваться несовсем удобно. Для приложений WinForms удобно использовать стороннюю библиотеку ZedGraph. 
Скачать её можно с [офф сайта](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/samples.html). Там же есть некоторая документация на английском языке. Ещё есть [русская документация](http://jenyay.net/Programming/ZedGraph) по ней. Также можно немного почитать на форумах [тут](http://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-beginners/thread176606.html) и [тут](http://www.cyberforum.ru/windows-forms/thread56873.html?uri=/windows-forms/thread56873.html)